# CakePHP - Losing Session Data between requests, but only on database

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

I am using Auth and Sessions in CakePHP 2.2.5, and I only have this problem when I use database for Session Storage.

I can see that the Auth data is in the database, but on page load, when Im checking the Auth data the Auth array in the session is null. Everything works fine when using php, cache, and file mechanisms. I am at my wits end here and this is a rather nasty production bug that I am facing. I am using the defaults for the `cake_sessions` table and all of the session options. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't done storing session in a database, but I have had similar problems when storing the session on a different server, of losing session between requests.  It turned out the servers were on different times, so it was acting as if the session was expired.  Perhaps the same could be true, if your session database is on a different server than your cakephp app.  At any rate, I ended up putting debug statements in lib/cake/model/datasource/cakesession.php in the _checkvalid function and _validagentandtime function and such to try to diagnose my session problems, to come upon the answer.

Comment: most of the session remains intact, its just the AUTH data thats disappearing. though I suppose that the rest of the data could be getting written on page load... will have to check that out.